# Collapsing toolbar with tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

What I want to achieve :

[image]

*this UI design belongs to* [Audio Beats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer)

and here what I have

[image]

. The problem is tablayout going behind the recyclerView when collapsing toolbar is expanded. And also I'm not able to remove title "Musico" or set it to the Top as sticky.

My xml is

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/hp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
app:behavior_overlapTop="30dp"
>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Move the TextView (MUsico) inside to Toolbar and provide a custom layout for toolbar (it will remain up on top)

Layout is not correct
Refer: [CollaspingLayoutwithviewpager](https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea)

Comment: Firstly, Musico is not a textview.I don't know It's title of toolbar or colapsingToolbarLayout. However I don't set title to any of them. It's the application name. Second, I already visited the link and it has simple tablayout with collapsing toolbar. But I want custom view like I showed in first gif.

Answer (score -2):

Just give the Tab layout a margin bottom of 30dp and increase the size of appbar layout if necessary.

Comment: Doesn't work. Margin remains same when view is fully collapsed.

Comment: Can i know If you place the TabLayout inside content_main.xml with a transparent background just above view pager. Will this issue be fixed?

Comment: Y..I tried that too but the output was quite a like but not the same as I mentioned in first gif. Overall this again not the solution.